# Create Mutable Array with name from NSString Variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dynamic, nsmutablearray

I have searched the internet quite a while concerning this problem but didn't find anything related. So I have a simple question: Is it by any means possible to create a Mutable Array in Objective C by using a NSString Variable to name it?

To be more clear a code example (which doesn't work this way):

```
NSString* someString = @"RandomWord";

NSMutableArray* (someString) = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Any help would be appreciated. If this does not work the way I intend to do it, it would be nice to know another way to dynamically create Arrays with reasonable, retrievable names.
Best Regards,
J

UPDATE:
I have an `NSMutableDictionary` in which I intend to save multiple `NSMutableArray` with URLs. The user can name the keys in the Dictionary himself.
For example: The user creates a category named "Animals" and stores multiple URLs in that category.
So what I want to achieve is to save the `NSMutableArray` filled with the URLs for the key "Animals" in the `NSMutableDictionary`.
I originally thought about just using one `NSMutableArray` but as I learned the copies of the Array in the `NSMutableDictionary` are only shallow, so each time I filled the array with something new and stored it the old values were lost in my `NSMutableDictionary`. But since the User creates as many categories as he wants and also names them how he wants to I need to somehow create arrays that I can reasonably retrieve and add as content to the `NSMutableDictionary`.
I know this sounds kind of confusing but I hope I made my goal somehow clear.
If there are any questions please ask!

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: please see edited question for details

Comment: Really I'd suggest just using a database, for something like this. It's very easy.  So, http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. You can, however, use an `NSMutableDictionary`, to store the instances.

An example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSString *someString = @"RandomWord";
[dict setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:someString];
```

Then to use later:

```
[[dict objectForKey:someString] doSomethingToTheArray];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I think with this input I can find a way to solve my problem!